# Making circular FrameLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm working on making Framelayout circular. When I google I got some suggestion of making xml file of it. I did it and in background to FrameLayout as my xml file. But it has no effect. My xml file for ring shape is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="ring"
android:innerRadius="15dp"
android:thickness="10dp"
android:useLevel="false">

<solid android:color="#ababf2" />

</shape>
```

I tried all ring and oval shape. None worked. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

New drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#6a000000" />
    <size android:height="25dp"
        android:width="25dp"/>
</shape>
```

In your frame layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/your_new_drawable" />
```

Comment: Setting background won't make the child view inside of it confine to its borders

Answer (score -1):

Have you actually set the background attribute in your layout, just making the shape is not enough, you have to apply it to the FrameLayout as well using,

```
android:background=""
```

Comment: I applied it. I clearly mentioned it in the question that I applied it for framelayout as well.